# Visual studio 6.0 (VC++ reference issue)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-6

I have the following workspace images of my project
[image: Image1]
I would like to know what are the highlighted components in Workspace ?
I tried to find out more about it by trying to access its properties but nothing was available. So I deleted them .But know if I try to build my **VeCAD_EXE project**  I get `unresolved external symbol` errors for the methods defined in **CAD_DLL project**.
I suppose it acted as some reference to my `CAD_DLL` project.
But I don't know how do I get those 2 components back again :(.

Any views of how can I achieve this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe dependencies? Don't have VC6 at hand any more ...

Comment: You need to upgrade your compiler. VC6 is notoriously broken.

Comment: @DeadMG am trying to migrate it to VS 2008 but having lots of errors with it. But will try to get it working.Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the dependencies that should be built before building VECAD_EXE project. Probably these project produce *.lib/*.dll that must be linked with main project and because they are missing you receive linking error.

To change dependencies for project go to Project -> Dependencies... menu.

Comment: Thanks mate,That's the thing :)